# Get all images from wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, image, post

With this function I can get the first image from a post by echo get_the_first_image():

```
function get_first_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
    $first_img = '';
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
    $first_img = $matches [1] [0];
    if(empty($first_img)){ //Defines a default image
        $first_img = "path/to/default/image.jpg";
    }
    return $first_img;
}
```

Can I change this code to get all images from the post in an array or something suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }

 endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

if you have any doubt then comment here

Answer (score 2):

Hi a while a go i was searching for the same thing the code below gets al attachted images from a post (be sure to use this code **in** the while loop)

```
$images =& get_children('post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$post->ID);

    if($images){
        foreach($images as $imageID => $imagePost){

            print_r($imagePost->guid); // for example the img path

        }
    }
```

Hope this wil help out. It worked for me also in combination with Custom Post Types